# Vertical align in bootstrap table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display a table with 4 columns, one of which is an image.
Below is the snapshot:-[image]

I want to vertically align the text to the center position, but somehow the css doesn't seem to work.
I have used the bootstrap responsive tables.
I want to know why my code doesn't work and whats is the correct method to make it work.

following is the code for the table

**CSS**

```css
img {
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
}
th, td {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<table id="news" class="table table-striped table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Phone</th>
          <th>Photo</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        $i=0;
        foreach ($result as $row) 
        { ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo 'Lorem Ispum'; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo 'lrem@ispum.com'; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo '9999999999'; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo '<img src="'.  base_url('files/images/test.jpg').'">'; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <?php
        }
        ?>           
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 331, accepted):

Based on what you have provided, your CSS selector is not [specific](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) enough to override the CSS rules defined by Bootstrap.

Try this:

```css
.table > tbody > tr > td {
     vertical-align: middle;
}
```

In **Boostrap 4 and 5**, this can be achieved with the `.align-middle` [Vertical Alignment](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/vertical-align/) utility class.

```
<td class="align-middle">Text</td>
```

Comment: @BarryFranklin Add a class to that table, `<table class="table vertical-align">`, and slightly increase the specificity of the selector using that class, `table.vertical-align > tbody > tr > td {}`. You could also do `.table.vertical-alilgn > tbody > tr > td {}` though that has a higher specificity than the first option. I always try to increase specificity in my CSS selectors as little as possible if I can. Notice that the first option is selecting a table element that has `.vertical-align` while the second option is selecting an element that has the `.table` AND `.vertical-align` classes.

Answer (score 47):

As of Bootstrap 4 this is now much easier using the included [utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/vertical-align/) instead of custom CSS. You simply have to add the class **align-middle** to the td-element:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="align-baseline">baseline</td>
      <td class="align-top">top</td>
      <td class="align-middle">middle</td>
      <td class="align-bottom">bottom</td>
      <td class="align-text-top">text-top</td>
      <td class="align-text-bottom">text-bottom</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 13):

For me `<td class="align-middle" >${element.imie}</td>` works. I'm using Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta .

Answer (score 5):

The following appears to work:

```
table td {
  vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

You can apply to a specific table as well like so:

```
#some_table td {
  vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

Comment: `!important` is overkill, adding way more specificity than is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

**SCSS**

```
.table-vcenter {
    td,
    th {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
}
```

use

```
<table class="table table-vcenter">
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.table thead th{
   vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`vetrical-align: middle` did not work for me for some reason (and it was being applied). I used this:

```
table.vertical-align > tbody > tr > td {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```