# Vertical align in bootstrap table not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, text-alignment

I'm trying to vertically align text centrally in a bootstrap table.

I've read the answer at [Vertical align in bootstrap table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27747072/vertical-align-in-bootstrap-table) and tried the solution, but as this bootply shows, it's not affecting the alignment. See http://www.bootply.com/OkzxyD2JSk

Can anyone identify what I'm doing wrong, and how to get the text vertically centered instead of aligned near the top of the table rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you use paragraphs `<p>`, which have `padding-bottom: 10px;` stated in file "type.less". To vertically allign you just need to make  top and bottom paddings of paragraph equal:

```
p {
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

look at http://www.bootply.com/qOt7aGzaJW